# How to display metadata in pyrocms

Tags: php, metadata, pyrocms

Hello i am new in pyrocms. I want to display metadata in all pages. I have added meta title, meta keyword and meta description from admin in all pages. But the metadata is not displaying in client site. So in which other file i need to change to display metadata???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change anywhere. Just goto your theme folder -> open metadata.html file and write this line.

```
<title>{{ template:title }}</title>
{{ template:metadata }}
```